# Sorting IEnumerable<int> in IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have an object of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`.  I need to sort the ints within the inner `IEnumerable<int>` but I am not sure how to do this.

I attempted to convert `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` to `List<List<int>>` to make the sort easier with this code:

```
var sortedResults = results.ForEach(x => x.ToList());
```

But I receive the error "Cannot assign void to implicitly-typed variable"

I also receive the same error if I to the sorting and the conversion all at once:

```
var sortedResults = results.ToList().ForEach(x => x.ToList().Sort((a ,b) => a.CompareTo(b))));
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) - since these are integers that means you can use the number itself as criteria:

```
sortedResults = results.Select(x => x.OrderBy(num => num));
```

Above assumes you want the output to be just a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` if you need lists, use `ToList()` were needed.

Comment: It's a List<List<int>> not a List<int> :)

Comment: Yea - fixed - question text had a formatting issue so I didn't notice earlier on

Answer (score 3):

```
var sortedResults = results.Select(list => list.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to draw an example of how to order using IEnumerable
I think I can help you understand how it works.
Observe the example, I hope have helped to you understand
Example:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        class Person
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int personage { get; set; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person[] p ={new Person{name="Alice",personage=10 },
                         new Person{name="Alex",personage=11},
                         new Person{name="Danny",personage=12}};
            IEnumerable<Person> query = p.OrderBy(ps => ps.personage);
            foreach (Person item in query)
            {
                textBox1.Text += item.name + item.personage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }

        }
```

Result of this is:
  Alice10
  Alex11
  Danny12